# Get updated rows count from SQLite in Android using a raw query?

Tags: android, sqlite

How can I get the number of rows updated using an `update` statement in SQLite in Android?

Note that I need to use some type of raw execute of a SQL statement, rather than do anything with `ContentValues` because I need a dynamic query.  Thus I can't make use of the `SQLiteDatabase.update()` method.  For example, I'm running something like

```
UPDATE my_table 
   SET field_name = field_name + 1
```

The methods I know of return void, e.g. `SQLiteDatabase.execSQL()`.  `SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery()` returns a `Cursor`, but the cursor has zero rows and its count is always -1.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could do your insert whichever way you want, and then do a select and use the [`changes()`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#changes) function to return the number of affected rows.

Comment: Is that method available in the Android APIs?

Comment: It's a sqlite function. You use it in `select` queries - independent of the language you're using.

Comment: Ah.  Great!  I'd imagine it's wise to wrap such calls with transactions.  So you'd do 1) begin tran 2) do update 3) get changes 4) end transaction.  It works, thanks!

Comment: @Tyler Collier Could you provide an example how to select affected rows after update? Thanks!

Comment: @Gosha, click the `changes()` link in Mat's answer for help on `changes()`.

Answer (score 12):

To expand on [Mat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6659693/1402846), here's the example code for getting the updated row count:

```java
Cursor cursor = null;
try
{
    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT changes() AS affected_row_count", null);
    if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0 && cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        final long affectedRowCount = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("affected_row_count"));
        Log.d("LOG", "affectedRowCount = " + affectedRowCount);
    }
    else
    {
        // Some error occurred?
    }
}
catch(SQLException e)
{
    // Handle exception here.
}
finally
{
    if(cursor != null)
    {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would use this simpler approach: `cursor.getLong(0)`.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on Mat and Pang's answers...

Could we skip the Cursor and use **`simpleQueryForLong()`**?

e.g.

```
public long getChangesCount() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteStatement statement = db.compileStatement("SELECT changes()");
    return statement.simpleQueryForLong();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete method for this:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
SQLiteStatement statement = db.compileStatement("[your sql here]");
int affectedRows = statement.executeUpdateDelete();
```

The same method used internally in SQLiteDatabase.update(...) methods.