# How to obtain affected rows of an update called through execSQL() or rawQuery() SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, sql-update

What is the SQL statement for retrieving the number of affected rows of the last `UPDATE` SQLite statement.  A MySQL example is `ROW_COUNT()`.  The `PRAGMA count_changes;` SQLite Pragma statment is deprecated and so I'm not going to use it.

I do not want to use SQLiteDatabase.update() to retrieve this information, I would like to know how to do this using nothing but raw queries, either by `.rawQuery()` or `.execSQL()`.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get updated rows count from SQLite in Android using a raw query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659673/get-updated-rows-count-from-sqlite-in-android-using-a-raw-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the SQLite [changes()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#changes) function.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be available in Android.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very late but I just wanna share this

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
db.execSQL(yourSqlQuery);
Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select changes() 'affected_rows'", null);
res.moveToFirst();
int affected_rows = res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex("affected_rows"));
```