# number of rows affected by insert sql / android

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get updated rows count from SQLite in Android using a raw query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659673/get-updated-rows-count-from-sqlite-in-android-using-a-raw-query)

I want to get the number of rows affected by a sqlite `insert` command. My query looks something link this:

```
String sql = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO "+TABLE_USER+" (`...
                ")" ;

        c = myDataBase.rawQuery(sql, null);
```

My research was not successful. I found something like a `count()` command for sql but I didn't get it to work. How do I get the number of modified rows of a sql `INSERT` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try with the `changes() function` to return the number of affected rows.

"The changes() function returns the number of database rows that were changed or inserted or deleted by the most recently completed INSERT, DELETE, or UPDATE statement, exclusive of statements in lower-level triggers. The changes() SQL function is a wrapper around the sqlite3_changes() C/C++ function and hence follows the same rules for counting changes." -- "http://www.sqlite.org"

Comment: and how do I count the changes then?