# Update statement in Sqlite that makes no real changes reports updated rows

Tags: android, sqlite

I have this table with an primary key column called `idcolumn` and another int column called `datacolumn`.

It exists already a row:

```
idcolumn=2
datacolumn=1
```

I execute this statement:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("datacolumn", 1);  
int count = db.update("mytable", cv, "idcolumn=2", null);
```

The result is `count=1`, even though no rows have been changed.

If I repeat the statement, the result is the same: `count=1`.

I need to know when an arbitrary `update` statement, really makes changes, in order to stamp a row as changed, for my sync framework.

How can it be done?

I've tried with and without transactions.  The result is the same, and with Android 4.4.2.

Related questions:

- [Get updated rows count from SQLite in Android using a raw query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659673/get-updated-rows-count-from-sqlite-in-android-using-a-raw-query?rq=1)

Comment: It's a duplicate.  I've searched before and didn't found this question.

Answer (score 0):

The `idcolumn=2` matches one row and it is updated, regardless of whether it actually needs an update. Therefore you get 1 as updated count.

If your data hasn't changed, don't write it to the database. Track changes in your Java code, for example add a "isDirty"  boolean flag to the POJO that holds the data to be written, set the object to dirty when a change is detected in a setter, and only update to disk (database) if the object is dirty.