# Return rows changed on UPDATE sequence

Tags: python, sqlite, apsw

I am trying to return what rows are used in my UPDATE sequence, to check if it actually updated anything or it tried updating a nonexistent row, but I am having trouble getting the actual rows returned

Upon asking friends and viewing other articles, I've tried using methods that they presented, like using sqlite3's `rowcount` method, as well as a RETURNING statement in the execute function, but both throw a AttributeError and SQLError, respectively.

```py
def set_reason(guild: str, warn_id: int, reason):
    warns.execute("UPDATE warns SET reason=:reason WHERE id=:id AND server=:guild", {'reason': reason, 'id': warn_id, 'guild': guild})
    return warns.fetchone()
```

Trying to use the RETURNING statement:

```py
warns.execute("UPDATE warns SET reason=:reason WHERE id=:id AND server=:guild RETURNING warns.*", {'reason': reason, 'id': warn_id, 'guild': guild})
```

I get `apsw.SQLError: SQLError: near "RETURNING": syntax error`.

And trying to use the `rowcount` method:

```py
warns.execute("UPDATE warns SET reason=:reason WHERE id=:id AND server=:guild", {'reason': reason, 'id': warn_id, 'guild': guild}).rowcount()
```

I get 'AttributeError: 'apsw.Cursor' has no attribute 'rowcount'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this APSW docs page](https://rogerbinns.github.io/apsw/connection.html), the `changes()` method is on the connection object, not the cursor object.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6659693/1261752) for a direct SQL query to get the same info.  Follow the link for more details about the function.  In case it's not clear, you just execute `SELECT changes()` and retrieve the result like any other single-result query.